# Give the name to the output PDF file from MYSQL database

Tags: php, pdf

I have been generating the PDFs and download it. Everything works fine. But whenever the file is output, it simply replaces the previous generated file.

Is there any way to output the file with the different name every time the NEW user downloads it by selecting data from the database?? What changes I can make in Output() method?

I have read [output() doc](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=125).

```
        $mpdf->Output("PDFs/something.pdf");

// change the path to fit your websites document structure

        $fullPath = "PDFs/something.pdf";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the answer given by Ramesh and some help from Immibis, I have found my way like this. Since the 'proposal_id' will always be unique in my case, so there will be no chance of downloading two pdfs of same id at the same time by different users.

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my_db");
$name="Select name FROM table_name WHERE proposal_id= '$id'";
$name_result= mysqli_query($con,$name);
$row_name= mysqli_fetch_array($name_result); 

$filename = $row_name['name']. time();
$mpdf->Output("PDFs/$filename.pdf");

$fullPath = "PDFs/$filename.pdf";
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
$filename = 'pdf' . time(). '.pdf';
$mpdf->Output("PDFs/$filename");
```

Comment: time() ?? What will it do here?

Comment: @Ramesh Yeah got that! Thanx but I just needed to know how it would be helpful here. I know what time() does.

Comment: Be careful. What if you coincidentally generate two PDF files at the same time?

Comment: @immibis Actually i edited this answer accordingly. But dont know why it didnt display.

Comment: I actually rejected that answer, because it "substantially altered the meaning of the post". You should write your own answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach some timestamp/date with filename.

$filename = "PDFs/something-" . time() . ".pdf";
$mpdf->Output($filename);

// change the path to fit your websites document structure

```
    $fullPath = $filename;
```